# for loop skipping first string in array

Tags: java, arrays, sikuli

I currently have an issue in my script where I use a `for` loop to iterate through an array of elements and check for their existence in the GUI. My issue is the for loop always skips the first entry of the array.

My current script is as follows:

```
public class GUIFunctionality {
    static Properties config = Data.getProperties("config");
    static int Pass = 0;
    static Screen s = new Screen();

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public static void loginGUI() {
        WebDriver driver = AutomationWebDriver.getWebDriver("firefox", config.getProperty("url"));

        // Test all GUI elements on login screen.

        String[] login_elements = { "loginbutton.png", "logintitle.png", "smalllogo.png", "remembermechecked.png",
                "signupbutton.png", "signuptitle.png", "changelanguage.png" };
        ArrayList<String> passed = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> failed = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String base : login_elements) {
            String file = String.format("imagerepo/config/%s", base);
            if (s.exists(file) != null) {
                System.out.println(file + " has been successfully found.");
                passed.add(file);
                Pass++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(file + " has not been found.");
                failed.add(file);
            }
        }
```

This script completely ignores `"loginbutton.png"`, almost as though it never existed in the script at all. I'm really stumped as to why. Here is the console output:

```
imagerepo/config/logintitle.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/smalllogo.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/remembermechecked.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/signupbutton.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/signuptitle.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/changelanguage.png has been successfully found.
Found elements: [imagerepo/config/logintitle.png, imagerepo/config/smalllogo.png, imagerepo/config/remembermechecked.png, imagerepo/config/signupbutton.png, imagerepo/config/signuptitle.png, imagerepo/config/changelanguage.png]
Missing elements: []
```

I'm wondering what I need to alter so the first entry of the `String[] login_elements` is included in the `for` loop. What's also interesting is that adding one more entry to the `String[] login_elements` will completely fix it.

Making this minor change: (nobutton.png is an image that exists within the repository, but not on the page under test)

```
String[] login_elements = { "nobutton.png", "loginbutton.png", "logintitle.png", "smalllogo.png",
                "remembermechecked.png", "signupbutton.png", "signuptitle.png", "changelanguage.png" };
```

This one change will now print this to the console:

```
imagerepo/config/nobutton.png has not been found.
imagerepo/config/loginbutton.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/logintitle.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/smalllogo.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/remembermechecked.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/signupbutton.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/signuptitle.png has been successfully found.
imagerepo/config/changelanguage.png has been successfully found.
Found elements: [imagerepo/config/loginbutton.png, imagerepo/config/logintitle.png, imagerepo/config/smalllogo.png, imagerepo/config/remembermechecked.png, imagerepo/config/signupbutton.png, imagerepo/config/signuptitle.png, imagerepo/config/changelanguage.png]
Missing elements: [imagerepo/config/nobutton.png]
```

This console output includes every entry within that array. Deleting "nobutton.png", from the array will bring us back to our original issue.

So what the heck is going on? The only thing I can possibly think of is a minimum number of strings in an array to include the first entry, but that just seems downright silly.

**Edit**: `s.exists(String)` is an instance of the `Sikuli` screen using the `exists` function to check for the existance of elements on the page. I really do not think this has anything to do with the error. I also could be completely wrong about this. I've learned most of the Sikuli library through trial-and-error (time-crunch around release dates is a horrible thing), so my ignorance on "why" is pretty high, which is why I'm here.

**Edit**: Remember, adding one more entry to the array completely fixes the problem.

**Edit**: Added the instance of `s`. The line `WebDriver driver = AutomationWebDriver.getWebDriver("firefox", config.getProperty("url"));` is an instance of a Selenium WebDriver I use to start the instance of WebDriver which I have to use alongside Sikuli because our web application is fubar (6 years of legacy code).

**Another Edit**: Source code for `Region.exists()` method and documentation.

[Source Code](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/master/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script/Region.java)

[Documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Region.html#exists%28PSC%29)

***This question has been answered. @Berger and @Andy Thomas have also provided some insight into what happens with the loop***:

> I think I have found the source code. exists uses a while loop based on a timeout value, among other things, so a subsequent call with the same parameter, could well return another result, see : https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/master/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script/Region.java - @Berger
>
> I see from [another Sikuli source file](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/master/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/basics/Settings.java) that the default autoWaitTimeout is 63 seconds, making the race condition easy to observe. Two important lessons from this question are: 1) A default case is frequently useful, especially if it's not expected to occur -- and 2) If you want a single return value, make a single call. - @Andy Thomas

Comment: What does "s.exists(String)" do, could you post the code ?

Comment: Add an additional else block after the ifelse block. Do you the first element there?

Comment: @Berger it is part of the Sikuli library. It's used to check the existence of objects.

Comment: I think your first array element is not getting through both your conditions. Add another `else` after your `else if` or better yet just remove the second `if` altogether so that you're left with `else`.

Comment: You say that you don't think `s.exists(String)` has anything to do with the error, but I think it has *everything* to do with the error. The first time you call `s.exists("imagerepo/config/loginbutton.png")`, it returns a non-null value. The second time you call it, it returns a null value. That is the only possible way you could have gotten the result that you got.

Comment: Could you post the API for what the `exists` method is? I'm guessing it's [this one](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Region.html#exists(PSC)) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Rainbolt You could very well be right too. Removing the `if` statement from the block fixed the issue, which leads me to believe that it doesn't concern the `s.exists(file)`, but once again, you could very well be correct. I think the weirdest thing here is that adding one more string to the array fixed the problem before deleting the `if` statement. The `s.exists()` documentation can be found here. http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Region.html#exists%28PSC%29

Comment: I think I have found the source code. _exists_ uses a _while_ loop based on a timeout value, among other things, so a subsequent call with the same parameter, could well return another result, see : https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/master/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script/Region.java

Comment: If you want a real explanation you are going to have to edit your post to include the declaration of `s` and any other context around your use of the API. For example, how is `s` populated and how do you know you can search it for string values.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a default case. You're using an if-elseif rather than an if-else.

```
for (String base : login_elements) {
  String file = String.format("imagerepo/config/%s", base);
  if (s.exists(file) != null) {
    ...
  } else if (s.exists(file) == null) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Your second condition includes a second call to `s.exists(file)`. **If neither branch is entered, the value returned must be changing between calls.**

You could handle this by adding a default case. An easy way would be to eliminate the second condition.

```
for (String base : login_elements) {
  String file = String.format("imagerepo/config/%s", base);
  if (s.exists(file) != null) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

**A debugger can help you find problems like this.** If you set a breakpoint on the first condition, you'd see that the first file is being considered by the loop.

Comment: This has fixed it, and had a good amount of explanation as to why, so I marked it correct.

Do you have any information regarding why adding one more element to the array allowed the `else if` statement to function the way I thought it would? It really bothers me that 7 strings in an array skips the first entry, but 8 strings in an array is just fine.

Comment: I suspect it's a timing problem. The return value for "nobutton.png" doesn't change, and the second call succeeds. Then that iteration provides enough delay that the first test of "loginbutton.png" succeeds. That's all a speculation.

Comment: @Berger - That's a good find for the Sikuli part of the question. I see from [another Sikuli source file](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/master/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/basics/Settings.java) that the default `autoWaitTimeout` is 63 seconds, making the race condition easy to observe. Two important lessons from this question are: 1) A default case is frequently useful, especially if it's not expected to occur -- and 2) If you want a single return value, make a single call.

Comment: I've added both of these observations at the end of the original question to help any poor sap like me that comes across the same issue. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not facing all possibilities:

```
if (s.exists(file) != null) {
    System.out.println(file + " has been successfully found.");
    passed.add(file);
} else {
    System.out.println(file + " has not been found.");
    failed.add(file);
}
```

Will throw an error with your same code...

Comment: I would ask for clarification in comments, not in your answer.

Comment: @Rainbolt agree if you cannot give the sollution, but my answer solves problem, if OP tell us what is `s` I would be able to detail and maybe fix the `if-if else-else` clause...

Comment: `s` is an instance of a Sikuli Screen. http://doc.sikuli.org/screen.html

I really don't think the s has anything to do with the error.

Comment: In that case, I would leave the part of your answer that solves the problems as it is, remove the question at the bottom, and post it as a comment. Or, if you don't actually need to know what `s` is to solve the problem, don't mention it at all.

Comment: @Rainbolt you know answers can be edited? A comment can be lost in futile conversations and trash opinions like we are having here...

Comment: @jagdpanzer are you sure? method `s.exists(String)` does not seem to appear in the [documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/screen.html) you linked. `s.exists()` has everything to do here because the return of this method will give us the possibilities you must face and if you need an `if-else` of `if-if else-else` clause.

Comment: @Jordi Castilla You could very well be correct. Sikuli documentation is extremely poor, my apologies. I wish I didn't have to use it. The `.exists()` method is mentioned here under the "Exception FindFailed" section. I essentially learned most of this stuff from trial and error, so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @jagdpanzer don't apoligize, we are here all for learning. I just wanted to know to check if there was only 2 possibilities (`if-else` as we all answered) or maybe you can handle 3 or more type of responses (in which case you will need an `if-if else...` or `switch` clause maybe... but if it works now, go ahead! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Java code should be:

```
String[] login_elements = {
    "loginbutton.png",
    "logintitle.png",
    "smalllogo.png", 
    "remembermechecked.png",
    "signupbutton.png",
    "signuptitle.png",
    "changelanguage.png"
};

ArrayList<String> passed = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> failed = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String base : login_elements) {
    String file = String.format("imagerepo/config/%s", base);
    File s = new File(file);
    if (s.exists()) {
        System.out.println(file + " has been successfully found.");
        passed.add(file);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(file + " has not been found.");
        failed.add(file);
    }
}

System.out.println("Found elements: " + passed);
System.out.println("Missing elements: " + failed);
```